# Counting number of rows in mysql once grouped

Tags: mysql

first time user so sorry if the formatting comes out wrong. not sure how to use this site fully yet.

i'm using php and MySQL.

in my table i have the customers name, address, email, the service they required and the total price

i want to be able to count how many quotes I have for each service, grouping by the email address.

so for instance if jack@john gets 3 quotes for 'oven cleaning', and then 1 quote for 'carpet cleaning', the count will show as 2. at the moment my script is just selecting the email address as the distinct value and not separating the 2 services which is no good as it's throwing off the stats.

Below is what I have for table QUOTES

```
Email      address           service          total
jack@john  123 fake street   oven cleaning     £100
jack@john  123 fake street   oven cleaning      £85
jack@john  123 fake street   carpet cleaning   £165
ross@joey  new york street   moving cleaning   £300
ross@joey  new york street   moving cleaning   £320
emma@high  the angel street  moving cleaning   £290

$sql="select count(DISTINCT(email)) as total from quotes GROUP BY 'email', 'service' ";
$result=mysqli_query($conSent,$sql);
$data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

return $data['total'];
```

The above gives me 3 as it's not separating the services, but the answer should be 4.

what am i doing wrong? I don't need any of the rows data returned to me, just the count as one number so that i can say for x month there were x amounts of unique quotes.

thanks

Comment: >  if jack@john gets 3 quotes for 'oven cleaning', and then 1 quote for 'carpet cleaning', the count will show as 2
Can you explain that a little more. How do you come to 2?

Comment: `DISTINCT email, service` ? you answered your own question

Comment: What a strange `GROUP BY 'email', 'service'` - grouping by a literals?

Answer (score 0):

> > count(DISTINCT(email))

would return the Count of 'UNIQUE' emails regardless of different services.
That's why its Total =3, as the grouped rows have only 3 'DISTINCT' emails.

```
$sql="select email, service from quotes GROUP BY email, service ";
$result=mysqli_query($conSent,$sql);
return mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Answer (score -1):

You need to group by email and service, counting service

Comment: The task does not need in grouping at all.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email, service) AS total 
FROM quotes
```

Comment: Can you add some context to explain how this will answer the question, instead of code-only answer.

Comment: @ArunVinoth Read the query as a text. "Select the count of distinct (unique) pairs (email,service) naming it 'total' from table 'quotes'". What additional context do you want/need???